# learning time series by machine learning

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gaussian-process, kriging

I am trying to learn a mapping between coordinates `x,y,z,d`, with `d=sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)`, and a scalar. Each `x,y,z,d` has an associated scalar; putting together the scalars corresponding to different `x,y,z,d`, one obtains a time-series. If I sort, for example, the coordinates by increasing distance `d`, and I standardize the coordinate `d`, the time-series, reordered to follow the sorted order of the distance `d`, appears, as a function of the standardized coordinate `d`, as follows:

[image]

What would be the best machine learning algorithm to learn this mapping? If for example, a Gaussian Process, what would it be its kernel?